How to compare and get the leftover objects between two SQL tables?
I have two tables: table_a and table_b. Size-wise, table_b is much bigger than table_a.
There are fields(names) that are present in both the tables. The goal is to find the names (or the number of names when using count): that appear in table_a but do not appear in table_b for the maximum date value.
We compare them using the names as you can see in the code below. Using LIKE CONCAT as the name from table_a could be a substring.
SELECT count(DISTINCT "Name")
FROM table_a
WHERE table_a."Date Collected" = (
        SELECT MAX("Date Collected")
        FROM table_a
    )
    AND NOT EXISTS (

        SELECT *
        FROM table_b
        WHERE UPPER(table_b."computer_name") LIKE CONCAT('%', UPPER(table_a."Name"), '%')
            AND table_b."date_collected" = (
                SELECT MAX("date_collected")
                FROM table_b
            )
    )

This query takes a long time to run and the values aren't matching up- meaning we are not getting an accurate count or list.
Are there anyways this could be made more efficient and accurate?

Please define the meaning of these "elements" that you say are found in both tables - is that a single field or ID, a subset of fields, entire rows from table A? Ideally, provide a little sample data to illustrate the problem.

You could also provide more detail on what this means with your result: and the values aren't matching up. What isn't matching up?

tag your actual database only.  is this mysql or postgres?

Please review [mre]. Example data and expected output would be particularly useful at disambiguating what is meant by present in both tables since the text description implies matching on equality but the query matches when Name is contained in computer_name.

Assuming Postgres, this should do what you describe:
WITH a AS (
   SELECT a."Name"
   FROM   table_a a
   ORDER  BY a."Date Collected" DESC NULLS LAST
   FETCH  FIRST 1 ROWS WITH TIES
   )
, b AS (
   SELECT computer_name
   FROM   table_b b
   ORDER  BY date_collected DESC NULLS LAST
   FETCH  FIRST 1 ROWS WITH TIES
   )
SELECT *
FROM   a
LEFT   JOIN b ON b.computer_name ~* a."Name"
WHERE  b.computer_name IS NULL;

CTE a gets all names from table A with the latest date in that table.
CTE b gets all computer names from B with the latest date in that table.
I use the fitting and typically efficient WITH TIES for the purpose. See:

Get top row(s) with highest value, with ties

The outer query only keeps names from a that are not contained in any computer name in b. Using the more elegant case-insensitive regular expression operator ~* there. Either way, if there can be special characters in your pattern column, you may or may not want to escape them:

Escape function for regular expression or LIKE patterns

And the LEFT JOIN / IS NULL technique. See:

Select rows which are not present in other table

The pivotal point for performance (and whether that's in fact the best query) will be fitting indexes for the query considering cardinalities, data distribution, and selectivity. None of which are clear from the question.
Also, consider proper, consistent, lower-case names for your DB. See:

Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?


Using ~* could result in incorrect results; e.g., if a."Name" has the value 'a.c', then the condition would be true whether b.computer_name had the value 'a.c' or 'abc'. The OP's original query has a similar defect that manifests when a."Name" includes characters that are special to LIKE.

@Erwin Brandstetter, how do I do a count of the output?

@JohnH:I added a link addressing special characters in LIKE and regexp patterns.

@winterlyrock: Depends. Please edit your question to clarify as requested first. And provide feedback whether my answer is on the right track.
